# finite $B$-algebra is integral, proof explanation

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

Currently I am studying a proof of the statement that for rings with $B\subseteq A$ we have:

Is $A$ a finite $B$-algebra, then $A$ is integral over $B$. Hence every element $x\in A$ satisfies an equation of the form

$x^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dotso +b_1x+b_0$ with $b_i\in B$.

The proof uses a "determinant trick", and I am not sure if I understand one step, when it is deduced that $\operatorname{det}(M)=0$ at the end.

For the proof:

Let

(***) $A=Ba_1+\dotso +Ba_n$.

Is $x\in A$, then we have $xa_i\in A$ for $i=1,\dotso, n$. Then there exist $b_{ij}\in B$ with

$xa_i=\sum_{j=1}^n b_{ij}a_j$.

We can rewrite this with the Kronecker symbol in the form

$\sum_{j=1}^n (x\delta_{ij}-b_{ij})a_j=0$.

We get a matrix $M:=(x\delta_{ij}-b_{ij})_{i,j}$ and a determinant $\Delta:=\operatorname{det}(M)\in A$.

For the vector $a^t=(a_1,\dotso, a_n)$ we get $Ma=0$.

Is $M^{\operatorname{adj}}$ the adjoint matrix of $M$, we get that $0=M^{\operatorname{adj}}Ma=\operatorname{det}(M)a$.

Hence $\operatorname{det}(M)a_i=0$ for $i=1,\dotso, n$.

[So far so good, now the part I do not see...]

Because of (***) we have $\operatorname{det}(M)=\operatorname{det}(M)\cdot 1=0$.

Oh, I think I just got it... Writing it down sometimes really help.

We can express (let me abuse notation here, and just name the elements $b_i$ too) $1=b_1a_1+\dotso +b_na_n$. Then multiplying $\operatorname{det}(M)(b_1a_1+\dotso +b_na_n)$ we get $0$, as every term just cancels because of $\operatorname{det}(M)a_i=0$.

Is this however correct?

To finish the proof we now "calculate" the determinant.

$\operatorname{det}(M)=x^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dotso+ b_1x+b_0$ for suitable $b_i\in B$.

This ends the proof.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: You got it! That's exactly right. Since $1$ is a linear combination of the $a_i$, it is annihilated by the determinant and hence the determinant is $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the verification.

Comment: Why exactly was this downvoted?

Comment: I really don't know. I don't think it should have been. I just put you back to zero.